# How to add a new member to a MailChimp list in a android app?

Tags: android, http, request, mailchimp

I'm developing a android application where I have subscribe dialog to collect user emails. I want to add those user emails to a MailChimp list. This is the code I came up with so far but with this I get a `Authorization failed` error.

```
public void suscribeMailChamp(String listid){

    String url = "https://us16.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/" + listid + "/members/";
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "success" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , error.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email_address","oshan@gmail.com");
            params.put("status","unsubscribed");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            params.put("Authorization" , "apikey");
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(sr);
}
```

Comment: please give me the error

Comment: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError with Unexpected response code 401 for https://us16.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/6e520e2c45/members/

Comment: any one know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but for anybody else having trouble, I solved this by adding the word "apikey" before copying in the api key, as below:

```
params.put("Authorization" , "apikey <YOUR API KEY HERE>");
```

Comment: I'm working in node.js and this saved me. This was how I authenticated to add a new user to an audience.

Answer (score 0):

in this line of code insert your API key

```
params.put("Authorization" , "apikey");
```

Comment: I know that bro. I put apikey there because I didn't want to put my real key. problem is even with the api key I still get the same error